# Plumber R post on server dosen't work

Tags: r, linux, api, postman, plumber

I'm building an Shiny-App with different API connections. It's all running on a server (CentOS Redhat).
I've got a problem with my API. If I'm running this on my terminal (Mac), everything works.

```
curl --data "InvestAmountInWei=2000000000000000000&Address=Test“ "http://s*******aw.ch:8002/invest"
```

Same with the Postman-App. I can do a post there and all will be done perfectly. The post request should transfer the ammount and the adress (like an id) to my r-script which is running via plumber.
As sad, if I do this command through terminal or Postman it works. But I need to do this command with the webbrowser.

I used this link to test it:

```
http://s*********aw.ch:8002/invest?InvestAmountInWei=1000000000000000000&Address=Jennifer
```

and now I only get this error in my web browser: `{"error":["404 - Resource Not Found"]}`

If checkt the iptables as well and it should be fine.

```
# netstat -ntpl | grep 8002
tcp        0      0 16*.**.**.*6:8002           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      28563/R
```

any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request to a URL in your browser, that's a `GET` request. If you setup your endpoint to support `GET` and `POST` requests at the same location, your browser and Postman requests should both work just fine.

If you want your browser to send a POST request, you'll either need to submit a form to it or use JavaScript.